# Air handling unit design

Tags: hvac

I am currently developing an AHU for all weather conditions.
I need the design process for calculating coil capacity and air discharge rate.

Issue is that, while plotting the process on psychrometric chart, you can give only 1 outside air condition.

So you would need to plot 12 different charts for a year (considering that the temp. is averaged out for a month, which I think is not the correct way to design) and choose the highest required capacity as design requirement.

Hence for all year air conditioning how can I design coil capacity and air discharge?? Any other methods?

Comment: You need weather data such as degree-days to work out the days where ambT is above / below the desired temperature then design from there - also consider all other inputs / losses...

Comment: @SolarMike I have the weather data. I know the inside room air design condition. I am currently gathering data about all heat loads. **But as the outside air changes over the year, for which condition should I plot the process to have all year weather conditioning?**

Comment: The outside air T is the degree-days T ....

Comment: @SolarMike sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I'm not sure if a monthly average would work the best here.  You might run into issues with the maximum and minimums in any given month being too much for the AHU to handle.